# Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined when trying to play an audio file on click

Tags: javascript, audio, onclick

Trying to add an onclick event to a div evelment with an existing function that plays a sound when a certain key is pressed

I've tried adding the playSound() function to the onclick in my div but keep getting an undefined error, key presses still work fine.  I also tried separating the function out which I can get to play the sound, but there's also a little animation class that is supposed to be added and I get the same undefined error when trying that

```
    <div data-key="65" class="key" onclick="playSound()">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>  

  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>

  <script>

    function playSound(e) {
      const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
      const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
      if (!audio) return;
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
      key.classList.add('playing');
    }

    function removeTransition(e) {
      if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
      this.classList.remove('playing');
    }

    const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
    keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
    window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
  </script>
```

I want to be able to both press a key and click/touch the letter on the screen to play a sound on animation, currently it is only fully functioning with keypresses

Comment: `var key = document.querySelector(\`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]\`);` looks like it could be undefined to me. Your div you click on does not need data.

Comment: Just add a click listener instead of using the `onclick` attribute. You basically do not have `e` (or the click event) defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting "Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined" because you're not passing any argument to your `playSound` function at `onclick` event handler and it is expected to receive an argument referencing the keyboard event.

A much more efficient approach should be making `playSound` function more generic receiving the keyCode itself instead of the keyboard event. This way you can call it in other places in your code without other problems.

You could also make a specific function for playing the sound when clicking to which you can pass the element as parameter.

This would be as follows:

```html
<div data-key="65" class="key" onclick="clickPlay(this)">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
</div>

<audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
```

```
// Receive the keyCode directly instead of the event
function playSound(key) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${key}"]`);
    const keyEl = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${key}"]`);

    if (!audio) return;
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();

    if (!keyEl) return;
    keyEl.classList.add('playing');
}

// New function to be executed when clicking
function clickPlay(el) {
    const key = el.attributes['data-key'].value; // Getting the keyCode from dom element
    playSound(key);
}

function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    this.classList.remove('playing');
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    const key = e.keyCode; // Getting the keyCode from keyboard
    playSound(key);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to revise your `playSound()` method so that it's able to play sounds based on a specific `keyCode` rather than a passed event object as is the case.

This abstraction allows you to reuse the same `playSound()` method for different event handlers - namely, the `keydown` event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {   
  playSound(e.keyCode);
});
```

and `click` event handler:

```
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  playSound(e.currentTarget.dataset.key);
}));
```

Taking this approach means that your script takes control of binding the `click` event to the `.key` element with `addEventListener()` in the same way your `keydown` event is bound. This is generally preferred over the inline `onclick` event binding (ie as shown in your HTML).

Please see the following snippet outlining the changes required (with a single demo sound to show this method action):

```js
/* Modify to use key keyCode instead of event */
function playSound(keyCode) {

  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);

  /* Extend saftey check */
  if (!audio || !key) return;

  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();

  key.classList.add('playing');
}

function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
  this.classList.remove('playing');
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));

/* Bind events in javascript */
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  /* Pass the keycode from key of element's dataset to modified playSound function */
  playSound(e.currentTarget.dataset.key);
}));

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  /* Pass the keycode from key event to modified playSound function */
  playSound(e.keyCode);
});
```

```html
<!-- remove  onclick="playSound()" -->
<div data-key="65" class="key">
  <kbd>A</kbd>
  <span class="sound">clap</span>
</div>

<audio data-key="65" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something more like:

```js
var doc, bod, M, T, I, S, Q; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
T = function(tag){
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
var sounds = {a:'clap', s:'hihat', d:'kick', f:'openhat', g:'boom', h:'ride', j:'snare', k:'tom', l:'tink'}, p, players = {};
for(var i in sounds){
  p = M('audio'); p.src = 'sounds/'+sounds[i]+'.wav'; players[i] = p;
}
onkeydown = function(e){
  players[e.key.toLowerCase()].play();
}
}); // end load
```